# how to apply atomicAdd to each of element of an array in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a code from `CUDA` example to atomicAdd a single variable

```
__global__ void myadd(int *data)
{
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = threadIdx.x;
  if ( (x%2==0) && (y%2==1) ) atomicAdd(data,1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int *Hdt;
  Hdt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  // ... CUDA initialization here
  myadd<<<20, 10>>>(Hdt);
  cudaFree(Hdt);
}
```

It works good for me. But I am expanding my code so I would like to pass an array instead of a number to the kernel

```
__global__ void myadd(int *data)
{
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int z = threadIdx.y;
  if ( (x%2==0) && (y%2==1) && (z>4) ) atomicAdd(data[z],1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int *Hdt;
  Hdt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(20*int));
  // ... CUDA initialization here
  myadd<<<20, dim3(10, 20)>>>(Hdt);
  cudaFree(Hdt);
}
```

But it doesn't compile, the error message is:

> error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" matches the
>   argument list  argument types are: (int, int)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with CUDA or `atomicAdd`. It's about understanding how basic arrays and functions work in C++.

Comment: In my understanding atomicAdd is not needed here since each thread accesses a different memory location (the z in data[z]) - there is no chance of them simultaneously writing to the same memory location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace:

```
atomicAdd(data[z],1);
```

with

```
atomicAdd(&data[z],1);
```

If you look carefully, in the first case you were giving a pointer as first argument to atomicAdd().

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, this is the way to solve the problem. But I have a question about the number of grids and number of threads. In the first code, if I run the kernel as myadd<<<600, 600>>>(Hdt); It runs without any problem. But if I use the second version myadd<<<600, dim3(600, 20)>>>(Hdt); all data returned are zeros instead. Is it because of the limit of number of threads? How can I check how many grids, blocks and threads support by my device (Telsa C2075)?

Comment: You really should check error after each call to a CUDA api. cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) gives you the kind of error. For the block size you can query cudaGetDeviceProperties(). Note that you should really read a basic tutorial on what is the block size exactly and how it relates to the hardware.

Comment: Check out cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID); to find the grid, block, memory support on your cuda device